# Jackson objectMapper deserialize to TimeZone

Tags: java, jackson

I'm having issues making Jackson object mapper to deserialize JSON into an object that has TimeZone field.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.mrbean.generated.java.util.TimeZone` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('America/New_York')
```

Here is the part of code where I'm trying to deserialize json to java object.

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, EmailRequest.class)

json = '{"toAddresses":[{"memberId":1,"firstName":"Firstname","lastName":"TestLastbc171f54-50e2-43c7-9640-d5116cdad11c","timeZone":"America/New_York"}],"emailId":"bcebda9c-ff7f-4874-a443-755c4549c187"}'

**EmailRequest.class** 

toAddresses: Set<Member

Member object:
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    memberId: Int,
    timeZone: java.util.TimeZone
```

> 

Any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: Post your code. Among other things, it looks like you might have some weird shading that's misbehaving.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- code is posted now. Thanks in advance

Comment: What language is this? It's definitely not Java, and it doesn't look quite like Kotlin.

Comment: I just wrote portition of code while objects I typed manually. It is java @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-